# Wordpress and Web to Lead after submission function

Tags: javascript, leads, web2lead, web

I am using a Form maker plugin for wordpress to create forms. The forms work great and are easy to use, but I do not have access to the code of the form itself. I can just access the data in the form in an after submission function. Meaning that I would need to be able to generate a lead from javascript. I am completely new to salesforce and I need some help with how I would set this up. What I am thinking is that I will start with something like this

```
function onFormSubmit() {
    //create json object with submission information

    //send json file to salesforce
}
```

I may be completely wrong about how salesforce works, but it seems like this kind of thing would be very simple. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to `Setup > Customize > Leads > Web-to-Lead`. From there you can click on `Create Web-to-Lead-Form` to generate the html that's used by the Form Maker plugin to create the Wordpress code. You'll have all the fields, etc used by your org for incoming leads.

If you click on Edit, you'd also be able to edit the Lead Processing rules.